# Get first line in each hierarchical pandas series

Tags: python, pandas, pandas-groupby, distribution, frequency

This is my Dataframe

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({
    "Gender": ["M", "F", "M", "M", "M",  "F", "F", "F", "F", "F", "F"],
    "Work-code": ["N1", "N3", "N1", "N1", "X15", "N3", "N3", "N3", "N3", "N1", "N3"],
    "Accident-type-code": ["1.1","1.2", "1.1","1.3","1.5","1.3","1.1","1.1","1.1", "1.1", "1.3"]
})
```

To analise this data I'm using groupby:

```
data = df.groupby(["Gender", "Work-code"])["Accident-type-code"].value_counts()
```

This is what I get:

```
Gender  Work-code  Accident-type-code
F       N1         1.1                   1
        N3         1.1                   3
                   1.3                   2
                   1.2                   1
M       N1         1.1                   2
                   1.3                   1
        X15        1.5                   1
```

What I need is just the first line of each inner group (the most frequent group for a given outer group), like:

```
Gender  Work-code  Accident-type-code
F       N1         1.1                   1
        N3         1.1                   3
M       N1         1.1                   2
        X15        1.5                   1
```

In fact, I'm doing this because I want to do a bivariate frequency distribution, but I don't know any function or library in python to do this.

Comment: why not just use `nunique`? `df.groupby(["Gender", "Work-code"]).agg(count=("Accident-type-code",'nunique'))`

Comment: @Datanovice very nice trick but here you lose the `Accident-type-code` information

Comment: or - `df.groupby(["Gender", "Work-code",]).agg(count=("Accident-type-code",'nunique'),name=("Accident-type-code",'first'))` you could add unique in too but it returns a list.

Answer (score 0):

*There are some changes that you need to make in your groupby section.*

```
data = df.groupby(["Gender", "Work-code"])["Accident-type-code"].value_counts().reset_index(name="counts")

data.head(1)
```

Now you have a normal table, you may use loops to find that out quite easily.

Comment: Nice idea, but I'd have to use 3 loops (one for gender, one for Work-code and one for Accident-type-code) to get this information and it is not eficient when the DF has hundreds of thousands of rows... (wich is my real case - I putted this just as an example of how I'd like my DF to be)

Answer (score 0):

ok, so you may try this.
**first, groupby reset_index:**

```
data_raw = df.groupby(["Gender", "Work-code"])["Accident-type-code"].value_counts().reset_index(name="counts")
```

**and then**

```
data_raw.groupby(['Gender','Work-code'],as_index=True).first()
```

**My output:**

[That's the snap of output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/W9cWX.png)

Comment: First groupby was for counting the value and getting it back into the table format. After getting it back in the table format, I grouped it by those two columns

Comment: Even I don't have enough reputation.

Comment: Nice!!! Thanks, I finished my job using your idea and it worked! :)